# Proper transformation file to go from NAD83 CSRS UTM 17 to NAD83 UTM 17

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, nad83

Looking to determine which transformation file to select when using the Project tool in ArcMap 10.2.2 to go from NAD83 CSRS UTM 17 and NAD 83 UTM 17.  The data I am working with is from Geogratis and will be projected to suit Ontario standards (NAD83 UTM 17).

Answer (score 2):

Esri software does not have a built-in transformation to convert between NAD 1983 and NAD 1983 CSRS in Ontario.

The Ontario Ministry of Natural Resources and Forestry provides an NTv2 file to convert between NAD 1983 (original) and NAD 1983 CSRS. You can download it from [COSINE](http://www.applications.lrc.gov.on.ca/cosine/cgi-bin/COSN_RetrFuncts.asp?task=gen_homepage). You have to apply, but it's not onerous, and the NTv2 files are free to download.

Once you have the .gsb flie, you should place it in your ArcGIS for Desktop install location in the pedata\ntv2\Canada folder. Next, use the Create Custom Geographic Transformation Tool to define a new transformation that uses it. In the tool, select the appropriate source and target geographic CRS, method is NTv2, and use the Canada\filename for the parameter.

Comment: Thanks kindly for posting this, I couldn't understand why there wasn't an Ontario-specific transformation available through ArcGIS.